# Help with "Error: No module named polls" from the Django Project Tutorial 1

Tags: django

I am working on this Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) and am getting this error: "Error: No module named polls" when I type "python manage.py sql polls" in the terminal. I have no clue how to fix this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you add `"polls",` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`?

Answer (score 18):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls' # THIS IS THE ANSWER
)
```

Comment: why is this the answer?

Comment: Works for me for Django 1.8.14 and Python 3.5.2

Comment: @awongh `polls/__init__.py` informs Python that it's a package and as per the tutorial `polls` is at the root of the project without any enclosing packages.  Hence it can be imported as-is, without any enclosing namespace like the other Django apps like `auth`, which is inside `django.contrib`.

Answer (score 10):

There is an error in the documentation. Type `polls` instead of `mysite.polls`.

Answer (score 4):

Ismael's answer worked for me.

Originally had

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/$ ,'mysite.polls.views.index'),
)
```

Changed to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/$ ,'polls.views.index'),
)
```

Comment: New to community. Couldn't vote up his answer due to lack of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have added polls app inside the setting.py please remove that and try recreating the polls and then add to the setting.py file. This solved my issue :)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        #Remove the below application and try again
        #'polls',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible that you missing "," after 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' in settings.py file

Answer (score 1):

This need to run one command after your changes in INSTALLED_APPS

$ python manage.py makemigrations polls

after that:

$ python manage.py sqlmigrate polls 0001

Answer (score 0):

You must create all these files in pool directory: **init**.py, admin.py, models.py, tests.py,views.py.
succes

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you actually stayed true to the tutorial and named your app "polls", otherwise things won't link up.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `'polls.app.PollsConfig'` to `'polls'` worked for me